# How to grab display picture on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I grab someone's display picture on Facebook? I want it for both friends and strangers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ID if you know it:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[Graph-ID]/picture
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture

This works with a global ID - meaning, if you know the ID without any App.

If you get the IDs with your App, it´s a bit more complicated. You will only get "App Scoped IDs" nowadays, and you will only get them from friends who authorized your App too. Also, you have to use an Access Token in order to make it work for App Scoped IDs:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[Graph-ID]/picture?access_token=xxx
```

You can also grab different sizes:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[Graph-ID]/picture?type=square
```

(type can be small, normal, large, square)

...and you can specify the size directly:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[Graph-ID]/picture?width=121&height=100
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for the
[docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture), let me know if you want instructions for specific coding or Programming Langugage on how to do it.